# Comparison of cellphone connectivity options

Tags: united-states, mobile-phone-plans

I recently moved to the United States from New Zealand, and given the amount of carriers in comparison, was wondering if anyone knows of a webpage that compares cellphone plans/pay-as-you-go options.

Alternatively, can anyone list any carriers that provide all/most of the following?

- Pay-as-you / prepaid
- Payments for connection/airtime that do not expire after as short as a month (Something like 3-6 months, or even a year, like in NZ)
- Allow connection of an existing cellphone, rather than requiring purchase of one of theirs.
- No contract

Alternatively still, if anyone has some knowledge about "data only" plans, that are mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/701/#13527), that would be appreciated.

I have done some research (Without much success in satisfying many of the above conditions), so if anyone would like to see this data listed in this question, please let me know.

Comment: google "BYOD prepaid cell"

Comment: gosmart.com seems to fit, is owned by TMobile

Comment: If we are talking GSM, the GSM frequencies are in 3 bands.  I don't know that a NZ purchased phone will be compatible in the USA, unless it is a 2 or 3 band phone... I used to have a 3 band phone 10+ years ago, but maybe all that is obsolete now ...

Comment: Paul - My phone is triband.

Comment: Looks like gosmart is monthly, but you can add up to $999 to your account on a refill, from a credit card. Doesn't say if that $999 ever expires...

Comment: If you wanted to be really frugal, you could just use Google Voice to get a US number, and use the Google Dialer to dial out.  That's not a cell phone, of course, but free wifi is pretty common.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, But I already have a GV number, and I need a cellphone in areas where there is no business's (Otherwise, technically, I could just pop into them and ask to use the phone, given the frequency of my need for communication away from home/work), hence (likely) no wifi.

Comment: To whomever down voted this question, please leave a comment to see if it is something that can be fixed.

Comment: No need for a downvote:  this is clearly asking for strategies to save money http://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Paul - 1) Or "Bing "BYOD prepaid cell"", seeing as they have this [helpful rewards program](http://www.bing.com/rewards/dashboard), and it is practically just a [copy of google](http://www.bingiton.com) anyways ;) 2) +1 for the "BYOD" term. Never heard of it before. Americans do seems to love their acronyms :) 3) Seems that http://gosmart.com is [not correct](http://i.imgur.com/KeD7gPr) - Where you meaning http://www.gosmartmobile.com? Lastly, I find it helpful to append the *http://* to the URL, so that it becomes a clickable hyperlink.

Comment: @user66001 About using the cell in areas with no businesses... if you intend to explore the national parks or go trekking in the wilderness several cell companies don't have coverage in true wilderness.

Comment: @MrChrister does that mean I can ask question on 'strategies to get a deal on latest ssd drive' or finding the cheapest drive?

Comment: @Paul - Not out in the wilderness, just residential neighbourhoods / golf courses on the fringe of city centers. So, did you mean http://gosmartmobile.com?

Comment: @user66001 Yes, though I only looked at their web site, and have not done business with them.  I have a traditional contract with TMobile and am happy with their network and customer service.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser - You could; see how the community reacts.  My personal opinion is that far more people need to save money on cell phones than get a deal on electronics.  The utility nature of a cell phone makes it on topic, while a SSD is too specific and localized.  I wouldn't mod-close either unless there were some existing close votes.

Answer (score 2):

Our Pay as you go phones tend do go on a basis of how much money you give them upfront. It varies from plan to plan. There are a few annual options available. [PagePlus and TMobile both do that]

- PagePlus [You can activate a third party CDMA phone]
- TMobile [GSM]
- Simple Mobile
- Virgin Mobile [Sprint]
- H20 - Mobile [Mostly for Data usage]
- Net10/Trakphone [has multimonth options]
- FreedomPhone [This is a new venture.. not so sure about them]
- Cricket Wireless [MetroPCS/Sprint network]
- Straight Talk [this is the walmart phone, its connected to the TMobile, AT&T, and Sprint networks] The phone you get depends on which network you'll be connected to.
- PTel - These guys are a SIM only option. You've got to bring the GSM device. This may be what you're looking for.

Nearly every carrier [with a few exemptions... i.e. Iphones] will accept an unlocked phone that will work on their network. You just need to verify that it will before you bring it to the network. It may require an ESN change or a new SIM card/regisitration. [The SIM card is binded to the IMEI in the US]

Comment: It won't help you with bringing your device in.. but its a start. All of the major contract providers have a prepaid option.. but they aren't so great.. otherwise I'd list them there... Sprint does a lot of MVNOing... Verizon does it a little [page plus]

Comment: "All of the major contract providers have a prepaid option.. but they aren't so great" - This is what I found also. What is "MVNO.." a abbreviation of?

Comment: MVNO is a reseller of the service/bandwidth

Answer (score 1):

Walmart sells several brands of prepay/pay-as-you-go cellphone plans and has stores just about everywhere; I suggest walking into a Walmart and asking one of the electronics employees about the plans they sell. That will give you some idea of the range of service plans out there.

Their website for [service plans is here](http://www.walmart.com/cp/1072335?povid=cat542371-env203289-moduleA052512-lLinkLHN3NoContract%20Phones_Plans), but you'll probably end up doing a lot of clicking. You'll want ones that will sell you a sim card (like [this](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Straight-Talk-T-Mobile-Compatible-Standard-SIM-Card/22288138)) to put into your current phone, and most of the re-up packs mention how long they're good for on the package.

Comment: Thanks Yamikuronue. I was sort of hoping not to have to travel to a bricks-and-mortar store, to make sure I got the best bang for my buck (Which probably won't happen, if I only visit 1 store). I agree that Walmart's website is not the best (Why, given their resources, I do wonder). Also, I would like to suggest that the SIM card link in the above gets changed to something like http://www.walmart.com/ip/AT-T-GoPhone-Sim-Card/22700044 given it is cheaper, satisfies my pay-as-you-go requirement (Seems the Straigh Talk option is $45 p/month), ...

Comment: ... doesn't state "compatible [phones]" (or the like) which I have found on many U.S., carriers websites (Should have mentioned this is my original question, as being an annoying aspect of U.S cell carries, i.e., trying to create doubt as to whether your phone will work with, for instance, the GSM standard), and doesn't have some [concerning reviews](http://reviews.walmart.com/1336/22288138/straight-talk-t-mobile-compatible-standard-sim-card-reviews/reviews.htm?reviewID=10821344&adid=bzv_tw_revshr_001&veh=soc_ac), though I think this customer likely has a locked **phone**, instead of SIM card.

Comment: @user66001 Pretty much every US carrier has restrictions on what phones can be used. Some of them state it more obviously than others. This is due to contractual agreements between phone manufacturers and service carriers.

Comment: I should have guessed so. *Love* this country :)